# "WHERE clause" in Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

So, Facebook is supposed to be retiring FQL... today(8.8.16).
Is there a way to make Graph API requests, with something similar to `WHERE` ...?

For example, in FQL, this will bring me my status-posts who got more than 10 likes (and nicely order them from top to bottom)

```
SELECT message, like_info FROM status WHERE uid=me() AND 
like_info.like_count>10 ORDER BY like_info.like_count DESC
```

How will you achieve this with the Graph API only? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way with the Graph API to do that, you would have to get all posts and do the sorting/filtering on your own. You can filter by date though, with the `since` and `until` parameters.

Comment: Not accurate. You can filter by dates for example.

Comment: @pabben i know that, but he is specifically asking for filtering stuff like "more than 10 likes", which is not possible. i will add it to my answer though, just to mention it.